# Firebird database - How to convert varchar charset to UTF-8?

Tags: sql, database, firebird

I need to know if its possible to **"convert"** a query result (SELECT) field (varchar) to **UTF-8** format. I need to get some data from a **WIN1252** type. The database is a **Firebird 1.5**. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `CAST` + `TYPE OF`, but I'm not sure if it will work on Firebird 1.5.

Comment: You are not providing enough information. What is the DDL of the table involved (and especially: what is the actual character set of the column), what is your connection character set?

Comment: @ValMarinov Thanks. I fin this on web:

CAST(field_name AS varchar(100) character SET UTF8)

Comment: Depending on why you want to do that, the source character set and the connection character set, that may not have the effect you want.